# Take items from observable when other observable is true

Tags: c#, .net, observable, system.reactive

How can I control which items are pushed through an observable **a** depending on the (boolean) values of another observable **b**?

I mean, items are in **a** are pushed only if last item emitted by **b** is true.

Observable sequence **b** should act like a pass filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I think I have at least a solution
It can be done with a combination of `WithLatestFrom` and `Where`.

In my real code, I have this:

- An observable of positions in a video
- An observable of booleans that indicate if the user has started a 'seeking' operation (by dragging a thumb in the video player arbitrarily)

```cs
positionObs
   .WithLatestFrom(isSeekingObs, (pos, isSeeking) => new { pos, isSeeking })
   .Where(x => !x.isSeeking)
   .Select(x => x.pos);
```

It essential combine the two most recent values and applies a filter on the "signaler".

Anyway, I'd like to know if there's a cleaner solution.

Comment: With the `CombineLatest` you may get duplicates if the boolean control sequence is toggled too frequently. I think that the `WithLatestFrom` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks @TheodorZoulias! I've updated the answer. It works like a charm + it's my first time using that operator.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred way to do this kind of thing is with a combination of `Publish` and `Switch`.

Here's how:

```
Subject<bool> subject_b = new();
IObservable<bool> observable_b = subject_b.AsObservable();

IObservable<long> observable_a = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0));

IObservable<long> observable_c =
    observable_a
        .Publish(published_a =>
            observable_b
                .Select(value_b =>
                    value_b
                        ? published_a
                        : Observable.Never<long>()))
        .Switch();

IDisposable subscription = observable_c.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
        
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.5));
subject_b.OnNext(true);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
subject_b.OnNext(false);
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(4));
subject_b.OnNext(true);
```

That gives:

```
2
3
4
9
10
11
12
13
14
...
```

I prefer `Publish`/`Switch` over `WithLatestFrom` as there are more variety of queries that the former handles that the latter doesn't.

Comment: This way though you won't get instant notification about the completion of the `observable_a` sequence, if it happens while the control sequence (`subject_b`) is in the `false` state. I guess this can be desirable is some situations.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, you do, because of the `Publish`.

Comment: You can check out [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RP4hcf). Successful completion of the A sequence is never propagated through the C sequence. Failure of the A sequence is propagated through the C sequence only later, when the B sequence emits a `true`. Uncomment the line `.Concat(Observable.Throw...` to test the failure case.

Comment: That seems to be a bug to me. It should stop.

Comment: Why? The `observable_c` is based on the `observable_b`, not on the `observable_a`. The fact that the `observable_a` is published is not important for that matter.